# when dev repo does not map 1-to-1 with production work tree, then is this a good use-case for git submodules?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I am fairly new to git and just figured out the basics of how to update a live website from my local dev repo, via the method explained by these guys:

http://danielmiessler.com/study/git/#website
http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto

('The one-line summary ^^^ : push into a remote repository that has a detached work tree, and a post-receive hook that runs "git checkout -f".')

All is well, but I have 2 problems that I hope I can solve with a little more fancy git footwork than I know how to manage so far:

- My dev repo actually represents much more than just what I need to push to the live site.  But I want to keep my local dev repo as is (with the extraneous folders) because I also use this dev repo to backup **all** my work related to the site (including the master photoshop files I use to create the site's jpgs, project notes, etc.), locally, to my backup dev HD).  I have a vague notion that I should look into git being able to ignore certain files/folders, but (without having looked yet) I don't really want to just ignore anything - I want to backup my **entire** repo using git push when pushing to my backup dev repo (local backup HD), but push only **some** of the folders when pushing to the live site repo.  I don't know how to do this kind of thing.
- The folders of my dev repo actually represent different areas on the live site, which are not in the same directory structure.  I mean to say that I actually need (want, if possible) to cause the post-receive hook(s?) to check out some of the folders/files of the live server tree **into** the web server's DocumentRoot, while checking out some of the other folders/files of the live server tree **outside** the web server's DocumentRoot.  I would have just made the post-receive hook checkout to the parent folder whose child is the server's DocumentRoot, but my dev repo's directory structure does not map one-to-one to the live server's directory structure.  I need a little fine-grained control (for just a few folders), so I can effectively tell the post-receive hook(s?) where each folder of the tree should map to, in the live site directory/file structure.

Thanks for any guidance!

Comment: This is not a formal "answer", but what I ended up doing, so I post here in a comment:  

Even though pretty sure git submodules would work for this.. if I pursued it.. I decided instead (for now) just to split my dev repo into 2 git repos.. and push each of them separately.. which allows me to 'go live' remotely the way I needed, as described in my OP.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are using the wrong tool! You are keeping the website and auxiliary files in a git repository, which is fine, but then you want to use git to deploy your project.

I would suggest something different: Use a dedicated tool for deploying, like **fabric** http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.3.3/index.html There are other tools out there that do the same thing but I happen to know fabric.

If you want, you can then push your repository to the server and have it trigger a post-receive hook which only calls `fab deploy`(or similar). However, you might not want your complete project to reside on the production machine. In which case you would call `fab deploy` on your local machine. (Possibly write different `deploy` functions...)

---

You are asking especially about git submodules. I can't see the use for them here other that it would allow you to have different folder structures on your local machine and the production machine. This could work (I guess) but IMO it is overkill.

Comment: Thanks Unapiedra,

Every time I dig a little deeper into git I see that it is way more powerful and complex than I'll need any time soon... but I specifically chose git as my backup/version-control/deployment software so that I'd get good (slowly) with just _one_ such software. I'm still trying to orient myself to git.. but given what I know so far, I'm thinking to attempt managing my different dir/ structures (between my dev & the production machines) with git submodules - or at least with git anyhow. Do you know a better way (besides submodules) to do what I describe in my OP, **with git**?